# Bitbucket and Git same time push error

Tags: github, bitbucket

Early I had only github repository, but now want used both github and bitbucket. 
I added a new remote git repository on Bitbucket, use **git remote set-url**.

```
git remote -v show
origin  https://github.com/My/remont (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/My/remont (push)
origin  https://my@bitbucket.org/my/remont.git (push)
```

Then run:

```
git add --all .
git commit -m "bitbucker"
git push -u origin master
```

Github added fine but bitbucket shows an error

```
Password for 'https://my@bitbucket.org':
To https://bitbucket.org/my/remont.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://my@bitbucket.org/my/remont.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Comment: how did you create a bitbucket repository? most probably you have created a repo with one initial commit in it (like default readme file)

Comment: Create default without any settings

Comment: and you have no commits in it?

Comment: Now I make first commits by delating string from readme.md. But nothing change

Comment: so... you did include a readme file when created a bitbucket repo? its a default option

Comment: check the https://bitbucket.org/my/remont/commits/all url

Comment: I make repo with default readme file and after made changes in it for the first  commit.

Comment: I have 2 commits now  
Initial commit and README.md edited online with Bitbucket

Comment: exactly. that is the problem. you have different commits in both repos.

Comment: And that can I do now?

Comment: you can `git push --force` to overwrite that commit